# Strange behavior using custom ArrayAdapter for Spinner Dropdown (duplicating items after click) (Android)

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, dropdown

I wanna use differents layouts for a spinner dropdown: one for the normal view (text + image), and another for dropdown list (just text).

So, at first, I tried the following:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_title, R.id.text, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Propably because the first has an image, and the second is just a TextView, I couldn't use this (always throw an exception - NullPointerException)

So, I created a custom ArrayAdapter for this, and it worked fine with the layouts, but another problem appeared: When I select an item, this item disappear from the dropdown list, and another item take its place.

For example, this is the initial state:

```
|item 1|

item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
```

Then, I wanna select item 4 (after select, the dropdown list hide):

```
|item 4|
```

And when I click again, to choose another item, it appears this way:

```
|item 4|

item 1
item 2
item 3
item 1
```

Does anybody knows a solution?
I want that all items always appear on dropdown list (with no duplicates either)!

Comment: Could you please show your adapter class?

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem with a custom adapter, in my case the solution was to replace this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);

        ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();
        holder.textTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSpinnerItem);
        holder.textTitle.setText(spinnerItems.get(position).getName());
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageSpinnerItem);
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

with this: (it seems like in some cases, when you click in a dropdown item the convertView is null)

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
    }
    ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();
    holder.textTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSpinnerItem);
    holder.textTitle.setText(spinnerItems.get(position).getName());
    holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageSpinnerItem);

    return convertView;
}
```

Hope this helps